# UITextview cursor moves to the end of the line

Tags: ios, uitextview

If i select a position in `UITextview` it place the cursor to end of the text (content).

i cant get the current position of where the user tap the textview.

Before click, when i click 6 in textview[image]

After Click , cursor moves to end of the textview and shows like this

[image]

Comment: can you show the code please?

Comment: Are you trying to get cursor location for a touch? Or the problem is that the cursor moves to the end after touch? Please be more specific.

Comment: @reecon No i didn't use any touch location

Comment: -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {  [NotesTxtView setFrame:CGRectMake(NotesTxtView.frame.origin.x, NotesTxtView.frame.origin.y, NotesTxtView.frame.size.width, 150)]; } I am changing the height of the textview in didbeginediting,. Is this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To know where the touch event occurred, implement this method in your viewController..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Now get the textView as touch object & place your cursor there.. I am just giving you a hint here.. Try to get a solution.. If there's any issue, let me know.. :)

**Update:**

If your textView is editable, you don't need to write any code there. Where ever you tap, cursor will appear automatically.

Yes, the code you are writing to change height of textView is affecting your tap & the cursor position..

Once you tap, textView is getting the touch rect, & then your method is being called. hence when the cursor is appearing, its appearing at same rect but different position with respect to textView. Let me know if more info is needed..

You can resize your textView after editing is done. This will solve your issue... :)

Comment: -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { [NotesTxtView setFrame:CGRectMake(NotesTxtView.frame.origin.x, NotesTxtView.frame.origin.y, NotesTxtView.frame.size.width, 150)]; } I am changing the height of the textview in didbeginediting,. Is this is the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys,.. i made a mistake,.. i wrote a method that scroll textview to the cursor point so it moves automatically to that position.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the **index of the cursor** you can just call:

```
NSUInteger cursorLocation =  _textView.selectedRange.location;
```

You can also implement a **UITapGestureRecognizer** and handle it with:

```
- (void)textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;

    // Location of the tap in text-container coordinates
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];

    location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
    location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;

    // Find the character that's been tapped on
    NSUInteger tappedCharacterIndex;
    tappedCharacterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
                                                 inTextContainer:textView.textContainer
                        fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
}
```